# Loop with break in the middle

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to create a gallery type page which shows one post thumbnail from each post category. The trouble is that I want to display the page title and a link to the portfolio page in the middle of a nine square grid. I was thinking the best way to go about it would be to display four thumbnails in three columns followed by the page title and then another 4 thumbnails. I've got the first four like so :

**Updated code:**

```
 <?php
    $count = 0;
    $taxonomy = 'category';//  e.g. post_tag, category
    $param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
    $term_args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
    if ($terms) { ?>

    <ul class="row portfolio-entries">
     <?php               
      foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $args=array(
          "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => 1,
          'caller_get_posts'=> 1
          );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        $post_count = $my_query->post_count;

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 

            $count++;               
            if ($count <= 4) {          
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
            ?>                      
                        <li class="span4 box portfolio-entry">
                                    <div class="hover-state align-right">
                                        <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>

                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <em>Click for details</em>
                                    </div><!-- end hover-state -->
                                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                    <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></figure>
                                    <?php endif; ?>                           
                        </li>

    <?php 
            endwhile;           
            } 
        endif;

      } /* end foreach term*/
      ?>                        
                        <li class="span4 portfolio-entry">
                            <header class="align-center">
                                <h1>Galleries</h1>

                                <div class="cta align-center">
                                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/portfolio" class="btn btn-primary">See Full Portfolio</a>
                                </div><!-- end cta -->
                            </header>
                        </li>

        <?php 
        if ($count >= 4) {
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
            ?>                      
                        <li class="span4 box portfolio-entry">
                                    <div class="hover-state align-right">
                                        <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>

                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <em>Click for details</em>
                                    </div><!-- end hover-state -->
                                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                    <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></figure>
                                    <?php endif; ?>                           
                        </li>                                       
    <?php endwhile; 
     } ?>
        </ul>   <?php
    } /* end if terms */
                wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    ?>
```

My problem is the second loop. I've got as far as the if statement `if ($count > $more_cats_to_show && $count <= $max_count)` but I can't seem to manage to get the next 4 thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a loopcounter based on the post number count - provides for more flexibility

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php $count = 0; ?>
       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <?php $count++; ?>
    // if you are in your first post
           <?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
    // do whatever you want to display your posts *assuming you want a featured top level*
           <?php elseif ( in_array($count, array( 2,3,4,5 ) )) : ?>      
    // do whatever you want to display your posts
           <?php elseif ($count == 6 ) : ?>  
    // do whatever you want to display your posts - this is probably the middle guy on a 3x3 grid with a featured 1st post
           <?php elseif ( in_array($count, array( 7,8,9,10 ) )) : ?>      
           <?php else : ?>
           <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So rather than stopping and starting the loop I would use css to display the elements in the right places?

Comment: Well, you can use CSS with the above to style differently, but you can also include different HTML elements within each numbered gap, example - after <?php if ($count == 1) : ?> and before <?php elseif ( in_array($count, array( 2,3,4,5 ) )) : ?> you'll spit out one post, which can include a title, picture, etc, and the next 4 posts in the loop - after <?php elseif ( in_array($count, array( 2,3,4,5 ) )) : ?> and before <?php elseif ($count == 6 ) : ?>, can include a title and an excerpt, etc.

Comment: The problem is that it is a post loop within a foreach loop so I'm having a hard time inserting content that doesn't loop. I think I might need to sleep on this one.

Comment: Your foreach will echo the items individually. So to break in between there try a counter (i.e.: `$forcounter`) as @Caroline suggested. And for your while loop, if you break there withing the individual items of your foreach loop, try another counter (i.e. `$whilecounter`). Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I need the `$whilecounter` as I am only showing one post(thumbnail) per term. I've almost got it (the page title is in the right place but it is only showing five of the six categories. I've updated the code. Still having trouble getting my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is 100% untested**, but you might want to try this/mess around with this

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach( $categories as $category ) 
        {
            $loopcounter = 0; 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();    $loopcounter++;  ?>
                    <?php if ( in_array($loopcounter, array( 1,2,3,4 ) )) : ?>      

                    <li class="span<?php echo $loopcounter; ?> box portfolio-entry loopcounter-<?php echo $loopcounter; ?>">
                                                        <div class="hover-state align-right">
                                                            <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>

                                                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                                            <em>Click for details</em>
                                                        </div><!-- end hover-state -->
                                                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                                        <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></figure>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>                           
                    </li>

                    <?php elseif ($loopcounter == 5 ) : ?>  
                        <h3>Title whatever this is goes here</h3>
                    <?php elseif ( in_array($loopcounter, array( 6,7,8,9 ) )) : ?>      
                        <li class="span<?php echo $loopcounter; ?> box portfolio-entry loopcounter-<?php echo $loopcounter; ?>">
                                                            <div class="hover-state align-right">
                                                                <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>

                                                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                                                <em>Click for details</em>
                                                            </div><!-- end hover-state -->
                                                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                                            <figure><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></figure>
                                                            <?php endif; ?>                           
                        </li>               
                            <?php else : ?>
                             <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; } wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
```

Comment: As is it just outputs the same image the number of times as there are categories but I see what you mean. I'll play around with it. Maybe `$loopcounter' as an empty array?

Comment: Ah, clever using the classes to count.